# Java Util Logger entring and exiting methods do not process

Tags: java

I tried to use the java.util.logging.Logger.entring() and the exiting() operations, however, they don't seem to be processing. Do I need to specify a Handler for the Logger or does it work without one similar to Logger.log()? In the code below, the logger.log() is the only method prints to the console but I do not see any messages from logger.entring() and logger.exiting() to the console. Any insights will be great.
Thanks,

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 *
 * @author hrh74
 */
public class SimpleLogger {
    private static Logger logger =null;
    public SimpleLogger(){
    logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleLogger.class.getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);
    //ConsoleHandler h = new ConsoleHandler();
    //h.setLevel(Level.FINER);
      //      logger.addHandler(h);
     for(Handler handler: logger.getHandlers()){
         handler.setLevel(Level.FINER);
     }
}
    public void simplyLog(){
        logger.entering(getClass().getName(),"In simplyLog");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "FYI..");
        logger.exiting(getClass().getName(), "Leaving simplyLog");
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleLogger simple = new SimpleLogger();
        simple.simplyLog();
    }   
}
```

By adding a Handler to the logger, the entering() and existing() operations are working, however, the troubling aspect of the updated code is the dual entries for each log record. Below is the snippet of the output to the console:

```
Aug 12, 2020 10:51:32 PM org.me.logger.SimpleLogger In simplyLog
FINER: ENTRY
Aug 12, 2020 10:51:32 PM org.me.logger.SimpleLogger simplyLog
INFO: FYI..
Aug 12, 2020 10:51:32 PM org.me.logger.SimpleLogger simplyLog
INFO: FYI..
Aug 12, 2020 10:51:32 PM org.me.logger.SimpleLogger Leaving simplyLog
FINER: RETURN
```

Now, if I remove adding a Handler to the Logger in the constructor, then entering() and existing() operations do not appear in the log but the problem with the dual log entries will go away. Here is a sample of the ouptut

```
Aug 13, 2020 9:43:55 AM org.me.logger.SimpleLogger simplyLog
INFO: FYI..
```

Comment: You need to add your expected out and what you have got

Comment: You can write it as a code so it would be noticable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#entering(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) for these methods. They log at FINER level.

A log entry gets printed only if its level is above that of the Logger **and** that of the handler that outputs it. In your case, your logger is using the root logger's default handler, which is a ConsoleHandler.

You need to set the root logger's handlers to log at the required level:

```
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
    for (Handler handler: rootLogger.getHandlers()) {
        handler.setLevel(Level.FINER);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. What confuses me is that I set the Level to the lowest level in the constructor. Do the entring() and existing() require a Handler object set up to work properly in addition to the log level of FINER or do they work like the log() method without a Handler object?

Comment: @Anthony _all_ logger methods work with a handler. The handler is by default set to info. So `logger.log(Level.INFO, ...)` also uses the handler. If you do `logger.log(Level.FINER, ...)`  you'll also see nothing. Until you set the handler to FINER.

Comment: Thank you k314159 for elaborating on this. Let me try your recommended code and see what happens. I will report back. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you K314159. I have added a Handler to the Logger, per your recommendation (see the updated code in the post). The caveat is that while the entering() and the existing() operations are appearing in the log now, I am getting dual entries for each Logger.log() operation. Any idea why this happens? Thanks

Comment: Yes, because you have added a Handler to the Logger, when it already had a handler. I didn't suggest that you should add another handler. My suggested code shows that you should iterate through the logger's existing handlers (by default the logger already has a handler - you don't have to add it yourself) and set them to the required level. (Note that the handler is the thing that does the actual outputting. The fact that logger produces output proves that it already has a handler.)

Comment: Thank you k314159 for the insight. I updated my code in the original post and removed adding a Handler to the Logger. The dual log entries certainly problem resolved, however, the entering() and the exsiting() operations do not log any entries into the console. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Now it's not printing because you've commented out the line `logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);` - so now the logger is limited to INFO and above even though the handler is now FINER and above. You need to have _both_ logger and handler(s) set to the required level.

Comment: Thanks, I uncommented the line logger.setLevel(Level.FINER) and updated my code in the original post, however, the entering() and exsiting() are still not showing in the console.

Comment: @Anthony you're right. I've just traced through in a debug session and found that the logger returns an empty array in its getHandlers() method, so the handler.setLevel method is not called. I will need to investigate in more detail and get back to you. Sorry about that.

Comment: I truly appreciate the effort you put into this. It is working properly now.